# Java How To Program: Exception Handling

Tags: java, object, exception

Hi I just started learning Java. Right now we are in class learning Polymorphism. But I am studying ahead and practicing Exception handling. I did 3 on my own but I need help with one more.

The question is Catching Exceptions Using Outer Scopes: Write a program showing that a method with its own try block does not have to catch every possible error generated within the try. Some exceptions can slip through to, and be handled in, other scopes.

Comment: What is _your_ question?

Comment: So, throw an exception in your `try` that isn't specified in any of your `catch` clauses?

Comment: It wants me to write a program. But I am not too good with words so I do not know where to start off really. They usually give us templates in class and we have to fill in the code. So Im just trying to get a better understanding and trying to figure out how to start it off. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Java has a very good tutorial suite called `The Java Tutorials`. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) the entry for exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This means, that method `A` elects not to catch and handle a certain type of exception, but it will simply declare, that it may encounter the exception and won't worry about it. If such an exception actually occurs in method `A`, the method will cease its execution and notify its calling method, that an exception occured. This is called *exception throwing* and it passes the responsibility of exception handling to the calling method.

```
public void readFile(File file) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((String line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
        reader.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

Normally, when accessing contents of a `File`, you would have to handle `IOException`, but this way, you declare, that it may occur and leave its handling up to the calling method.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I kind of understand

Comment: good explanation! just to add: it could also be that you catch the IoException but not any possible NullPointerException. In my experience... well inyour case this is highly unlikely...just to make a point: you can catch one exception (good IDEs will make you aware that there will be an Exception thrown) but some other Exception can still slip through (e.g. NullPointerException that is not allways thrown explicitely)